# manual installation of Web Developer addon in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, github, google-chrome-extension

There's very little documentation at GitHub:

> The extension can be installed in Chrome by loading the unpacked
>   extension in build/chrome as described in the Chrome documentation.
>   The extension can be installed in Firefox by installing
>   web-developer-firefox.xpi like a regular extension or automatically
>   with ant install.firefox and the Extension Auto-Installer extension.

Anyone knows how to install in Chrome using the GitHub master zip? When I downloaded the master files, I noticed there isn't a build/chrome folder, so maybe this information is out of date.

UPDATE: Using the unpackaged extension method, I get an alert that makes me move several files in order to recreate the file structure specified in `manifest.json`, but I get stuck with an alert that states:

> Default locale was specified, but _loacles subtree is missing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load an Extension from git-hub for testing , follow these steps:

- Visit `chrome://extensions` in your browser (or open up the settings menu by clicking the icon to the far right of the Omnibox and select Extensions under the Tools menu to get to the same place).
- Ensure that the Developer Mode checkbox in the top right-hand corner is checked.
- Click Load unpacked extension… to pop up a file-selection dialog.
- Navigate to the directory in which your extension files live(Go to Root Folder of manifest.json file) , and select it.

Comment: Thank you for this tip. I had tried it already, but I get the alert I included in my original post.

Comment: Basically, what I had to do was to move several folders (background, javascript, etc) into the configuration/chrome folder, but all came to a halt with the _locales alert.

I have solved my problem by connecting my PC to my mobile using USB Tethering and connecting to the Chrome Web Store, but if someone can still come up with a solution, I think it could be very useful.